# Consulta Hibernate-Java

Tags: java, hql

Hola me encuentro trabajando en hibernate y no conozco mucho del tema y estoy intentando sacar una consulta en hql, pero por mas que busco como hacerla no logro encontrar la manera ya que es una consulta multitabla entre cargo, asignacion_cargo_instructor e instructor y llego hasta cierto punto pero la consola HQL Query siempre me manda error esta es la consulta en mysql

```
SELECT `cargo`.`Nombre`
FROM `cargo`
LEFT JOIN `asignacion_cargo_instructor` ON `asignacion_cargo_instructor`.`fkCodCargo` = `cargo`.`CodCargo`
LEFT JOIN `instructor` ON `asignacion_cargo_instructor`.`fkIdInstructor` = `instructor`.`Id`where instructor.idInstructor= idinstructor and instructor.ClaveInstructor=claveInstructor
```

y esta es la consulta que llevo en codigo hql

```
SELECT cargo.nombre
FROM Cargo
as cargo INNER JOIN   cargo.asignacionCargoInstructors ON AsignacionCargoInstructor.cargo = cargo.codCargo LEFT  JOIN   Instructor ON  asignacion_cargo_instructor.fkIdInstructor = instructor.id where instructor.idInstructor= idinstructor and instructor.ClaveInstructor=claveInstructor
```

no es muy distinto, pero desde donde esta subrayado ya no me quiere funcionar, me manda error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'null.cargo'
```

quisiera saber si alguien podria ayudarme o pasarme un buen articulo que explique como hacer estas sentencias

Comment: @JoeDiaz ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Respecto a tu pregunta, te *comento* que la documentación oficial más reciente de Hibernate la puedes encontrar [aquí](http://red.ht/2b2gg0Z "Hibernate ORM 5.2 User Guide"). También hay una traducción al español, aunque es para la versión 3.5, [aquí](http://red.ht/2b2gdCA "HIBERNATE - Persistencia relacional para Java  idiomático").

Comment: `INNER JOIN   cargo.asignacionCargoInstructors` <-- no hay una `"s"` de más?

Comment: si , se me paso pero en el codigo esta sin s y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: y me sigue marcando error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'null.cargo'

Comment: el problema es que `AsignacionCargoInstructor` es null, mira el código previo a la consulta, cuando consigues la instancia de ese objeto, porque no esta recuperando nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mismo mensaje de error te indica el problema:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:
>   'null.cargo'

El valor de: 
`AsignacionCargoInstructor` tiene un valor null, revisa y asegura se obtenga un valor correcto, esto para que tu query se construya correctamente.